# How to protect a file on AWS lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda

I am creating a lambda function to be deploy on AWS but this lambda has to public messages on Google PubSub so I have to add to my repository the file .Json with the user to connect to Google cloud but I do not know how to protect that file, Can someone explain to me if is there any way to do it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to store the user info in the lambda.  Can you not use Lambda environment variables, or AWS Secrets Manager.

Comment: Well, I am not sure but that's how Google PubSub works, it give you a json file with the user and you set a environment variable with the path of that file.

Comment: If it needs to be a file, then the Lambda function could retrieve the credentials from the AWS Secrets Manager and create the file in the `/tmp/` directory, and then points the environment variable to that file. Can you link to some documentation about this JSON file?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Sure, https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started  however I am gonna try by creating the file on /tmp/ directory on runtime, Thanks

Comment: What is in this JSON file? Is it your payload? It seems highly unlikely that Google's pub/sub API requires you to provide a path (or a signed or public URL) to a JSON file.

Comment: The JSON file probably contains [the credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_variable). You could pass them via environment variables and just pass them as an object to the Google Cloud API client instead of having the API client read a JSON file behind the scenes.

Comment: @cbr Ah, OK so the key file indicted by GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.

Answer (score 0):

- You store the key-value pairs in environmental variables.
- Enable encryption at rest and transit. [image]